# DB-Library not loading, SQL Client Configuration

Tags: sql-server, client

When I open Client Network Utility (cliconfg.exe) on my laptop it generates an error that

> C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTWDBLIB.DLL is either not designed to run on
>   Windows or it contains an error. etc.

It then opens. Clicking on the DB-Library Options tab that generates the error again. When it does display it states the Version: as `"Not Loadable"`.

What are some methods I could use to try and fix this please?

I believe this may be related to issues I'm having with a 3rd party exe using VB6 that is having issues connecting to one of our SQL2008R2 boxes (it connects to other servers of this version fine).

Edit: I did fix the connection issue, but this not loadable error was not the cause of it so it would be nice to fix. (The actual issue was expired credentials stored in Credential Manager)

Comment: As the error clearly says, either the DLL is malformed or your software is.

Comment: @TomV Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: @clifton_h That's great to hear, what are some ways that could be fixed?